# Ionic 2 Native HTTP.post performing get on server

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm trying use cordova-plugin-http to perform POST request in Ionic 2 app.
But when I run, it's running GET method at server.

```
import { HTTP } from 'ionic-native';

login(username:string, password:string){
    return HTTP.post(APIHOST + 'login', {username:username, password:password},{});
}
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: probably u need to find a different way to call your api, may be that will work

Comment: Why this plugin doens't work for POST method?

Comment: this plugin is perfect, but did u import this in your TS file?

Comment: Yes import { HTTP } from 'ionic-native';

Comment: i am importing from @angular/http , and it's working well at my end . i have answered it below, may be it solves

Answer (score 0):

```
//you need to import this//

    import { Http, Headers, URLSearchParams, Request, RequestMethod, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';     

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private http: Http, private navParams: NavParams){}
        //login function
          Login(username, password) {
             //body for your details to be verified
        let data = {
                    "username": username,
                    "password": password,
                  }
    //here you are making an api call//
                  return this.http
                    .post(apiUrl + Login, data)
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .subscribe(
                    data => {
            },
                    err => {

                      console.log("ERROR!: ", err);
                    }
                    );
            }
```

Comment: Ok, but is not the native plugin HTTP https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/http/

Comment: i hope u are working with angular2 , and then u may follow the above mentioned import , to get your things worked

Comment: I would like to use native HTTP not from '@angular/http'.

Comment: what I can say is that '@angular/http' is an implementation of Angular 2 that returns an observables object.

And ionic-native is an implementation of the cordova-plugin-http plugin available at 'https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP' that does not return an observables, it works in the traditional way, if I can use that analogy.

But I believe that using 'angular/http' is better because it implements the same code and is more integrated with the structure of Angular 2.

Comment: Using plugin all requests are done in a background thread, is it not a advantage?

Comment: during the development of an optimized app , we keep all calls and plugin requests to angular. This actually makes application faster. Ionic has a lot to do in the background , from running with  all the scripts to creating your apk , and this process needs to be faster. Hence making requests or importing modules from angular makes it more quicker and reliable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137355/discussion-between-rayashi-and-devanshsadhotra).